# Can't access session variable in Kohana controller

Tags: php, session, kohana

I have mysterious issue with kohana framework.

I create session variable in controller function:

```
public function action_authorise()
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["user"] = "superAdmin";
    }
```

Later in the same controller's another function I try to access this season:

```
public function action_getSession()
    {
        $this->template->test = $_SESSION["user"];
        $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/main');
    }
```

The problem is that when I call $test variable in admin/main view it returns empty string, but if I call implicitily $_SESSION["user"] in admin/main view, it returns "superAdmin" as it should.

Can anyone see mistake while calling session variable in controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're passing the variable test to the view `template` and it needs to be passed to the view `admin/main`. You can do this a couple of ways, pick whichever one you like best:

```
// Create the view object
$partial_view = View::factory('admin/main');
// Assign the session value to the partial view's scope as `test`
$partial_view->test = $_SESSION["user"];
// Assign the partial view to the main template's scope as `content`
$this->template->content = $partial_view;
```

Shortcut syntax:

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('admin/main', array(
    'test' => $_SESSION['user'],
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You passing `test` variable to `template` view, but trying to access it it `admin/main` view. There is no `test` variable in `admin/main` view. These are different views. Each one has its own variables.

You should set `test` to `admin/main` view like:

```
public function action_getSession()
    {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/main')
            ->set('test', $_SESSION["user"]);
    }
```

Also there is very usefull `Session` class in Kohana. It takes care of session business within framework.

Take a look at [user guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/sessions).